# refresh a checkbox after changing with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, label, refresh

I have two checkboxes, one with a `label`, one without:

```js
$('#b').click(function() {
  $('#ch1').prop('checked', true);
  $('#ch3').prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ch1">Box 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="check2" />
<button id="b">click here</button>
```

After a click on the button, both checkboxes seem to be checked, but only the second one shows the "tick". How can I refresh the labeled checkbox?

Comment: both are checked on clicking button.

Comment: It's the css file: add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refresh checkbox with `.checkboxradio('refresh')`, after you change its state with `prop` in [jQuery Mobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/#method-refresh). Here is example:

```js
$('#b').click(function() {
    $('#ch1, #ch3').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label for="ch1">Box 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="check2" />
<button id="b">click here</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as intended?

```js
$('#b').click(function() {
    $('#ch1').prop('checked', true);       
    $('#ch3').prop('checked', true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="ch1">Box 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="check1"/>          
<input type="checkbox" id="ch3" name="check2"/>
<button id="b">click here</button>
```

Comment: It is the css file.
Add
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
and only the second checkbox works.